# Windows 7 starts normally when trying to boot from USB

Tags: boot, usb, bios, bootable-media

***Operating System***: Windows 7 Home Premium

The title pretty much says it all, I'm trying to format this laptop of mine and I can't do so, because **windows is booting normally
When I click on USB option to boot from**. I've tried several USBs (both USB 2.0 and USB 3.0), all are working on other PCs, burned windows on them using Rufus. I unplugged the laptop from electricity completely, tried again, nothing worked, tried to play with Bios options, there isn't much to do there anyways, I'll attach some screenshots of the laptop specs and its BIOS version etc.

[System Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39PRl.jpg)

[Boot Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mOlm.jpg)

[BIOS System Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hnMZ.jpg)

Any help's appreciated, thank y'all in advance!

Comment: You failed to indicate which version of Windows you are running.  Please edit your question and include this vital information.

Comment: Oh my bad didn't think it'd matter, done.

Comment: Windows 7 does not support being installed from USB 3.0 unless you add the necessary drivers to the ISO.  How that is accomplished is well documented

Comment: Tried using USB 2.0, led to no avail..

Comment: Make and specific model of PC???

Comment: HP G62 Notebook PC

Answer (score -2):

Some computers do not detect any USB's existence until after Windows starts.  There is usually a toggle for this in the BIOS but not always.

Comment: Well.. such thing isn't found in my case, and apparently it's detecting my USB as it's displayed in the boot manager.. right?